# Why are my machine learning images so messy?

Tags: image, numpy, machine-learning, python-imaging-library

I'm doing machine learning with Keras and my neural networks output images.

My data is normalized, so I take the output of my networks and un-normalize them, and then convert them into PIL images using `Image.fromarray`, and then display those images.

However, the images I get look really messy. For example they look like:
[image: Messy 1]

or

[image: Messy 2]

when they should be looking like

[image: Good 1]

My loss is going down to fairly low numbers, and when I look at the output values from the network, they appear to be fairly normal.

Why are these images showing up so messy? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please note, this is a self-answered question, so downvotes really make me sad. (If you are going to leave one, please let me know what I can do to make this question (and answer) better.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the output of your network isn't perfectly within the range [0, 255].

Even if you use a `sigmoid` function for the last layer of your network (which will guarantee your output to be in the range (0, 1)), when you "unaverage" the images, you may be somehow manipulating them above or below the [0, 255] range.

This usually has to do with how you're averaging your images. In my case, I think it was because when I averaged my images, I had a small epsilon in the case of a divide by zero. When unaveraging, this caused an issue where the values would get out of the [0, 255] range.

The solution is to force your array into the [0, 255] range before you turn it in to a PIL image.

I do this with:

```
image_array = np.minimum(image_array, np.full(image_array.shape, 255))
image_array = np.maximum(image_array, np.full(image_array.shape, 0))
```

This does an element-wise comparison twice for the array, setting the values to 255 if they're over 255, and to 0 if they're under 0.

You can then use the resulting `image_array` and convert it into a PIL image with `Image.fromarray(image_array)` like you've been doing.

The image you get out should look something more like that good image you posted in your question. (In fact, in your case, it should look *exactly* like that good image you posted ;) )

Comment: You answered yourself after not even a minute has passed from your post, lol.

Comment: @MattiaRighetti haha yeah, you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I tend to do that when there's a bug that took me some time to figure out, and it would be nice if when other people searched the internet to it they came across my solution instead of having to take all the time to figure it out on their own. (And even if my solution doesn't work, it might help them in some other way.) Just spreading the knowledge :)